# Need to rewrite a java class located in a closed-source jar , within my own program

Tags: java

I have the following problem:

- I'm writing code and would like to use a java bean in a package which I cannot alter its source.
- This package has a bug, at the given java bean. The solution in my case will be to remove this field (if I had the source) + recompile.
- I would like to write the same package + class in my source (as I don't have the source of the jar), without the problematic field.
- The real scenario is a bit more complicated.

I would like to consult with you what is the best way to do this before start implementing.

Comment: Ordering the jar's will effect the CLASSPATH, but I am not sure about the classes that are adjacent to the class in same package.. I need to try it once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are most probably looking for [Adapter Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) here. However keep in mind using this pattern you won't be altering/modifying original class but an inherited class of your own (in the same package though).

Comment: Adapter design pattern will not work. I have a specific reference in the system to the full class name, and I cannot use adapter, wrapper or something like that.

Comment: In that case I afraid there is not easy solution of this problem. You can probably decompile the provided `.class` file and change the generated source code to get desired results.

Comment: actually, I can't. Technically I can - but I will have some issues with shipping to the customers, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

How about reverse engineering the original source code, writing your own bean and adding it to the jar? Of course if the jar's license doesn't prohibit this approach.

It's relatively simple and modern reverse engineering tools provide you readable source code.

There are lots of tools enabling the reverse engineering of a compiled class. I recently used one as an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just rewrite the same java bean with the same package structure & set classpath order such that the user defined code is referred first rather than the jar file

Comment: sounds interesting. how can i do that? simply by ordering the jars at the classpath?

Comment: yes, classloader takes the first found class with the given name.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov - and is it guaranteed that the order is based on jars order? (the new code will be in the same jar as the class containing the static main method)

Comment: @zaske yes, the order of jars makes the jvm to look for that class in the CLASSPATH order only. I am sure it works for the adjacent classes also...

Comment: @Harsha and AlexeiKaigorodv - links supporting your claims will be very helpful to me!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really altering existing source code in a jar (maybe I'm wrong here but don't now a way). What you can do is working on class loading level and with aspect oriented approaches (like byte code manipulation). With that you can change source code of a class, method, etc. when its loaded. But I would'nt really recommend it, its just if you REALLY want it, then it could be a possibility.

Comment: although i fully agree with you (and i would even say this is "bad code") - i must do it , unfortunately :(

Comment: i fully agree with the phrase "bad code", but just in terms of your situation of course. but you cannot avoid it i guess. aspects makes onlz sense if you want to avoid duplicated code often introduced if you have to develop a middleware with massive security or logging code. would be great if you write back when you definitly went with this approach. it would be interesting for me as well. ;)

Comment: This is a standalone application, and the problem is that I'm working with "already serialized data" - (I have a deserialization exception due to bad instantiation of a given field to begin with), so using all kinds of tricks to "Proxify" the class will yield in different class than the one which is written in the binary serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Do you now Spring Aspects? You could try configure a Pointcut to intercept your method calls and using 'Around advice' to call your own code and avoid the original . More info : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: I cannot use spring at my source. <BR> It should be as less dependent as possible on other jars.